# QWebView with multiple frames/pages sharing the same session data

Tags: c++, qt4, qtwebkit

I have a QWebView, and it loads a certain page, the user logs in and goes about his business. This all works fine.

What I would like to do is have a second frame/pae open, that uses the logged in users session and all that jazz to load a reports page that it will render to an image file for display on a little USB screen.

Right now, I accomplish this with a completely different webView, which can't access protected pages, which is a bit of a security risk.

Here is some pseudo code for what I am thinking of:

```
webView->mainFrame->loadNormalUrl
secretFrame = webView->createSecretFrame
secretFrame->useSessionOf(webView->mainFrame)
secretFrame->loadReportUrl
secretFrame->doStuffThatAlreadyWorks
```

Any help, pointers, links would be super helpful! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,

This question didn't receive and answer, so I pattered off to the qtwebkit mailing list, and they were very helpful.

The essential thing is to subclass QNetworkCookieJar, the most important method being the loading from disk, which you call in your constructor.

```
QList<QNetworkCookie> cookies;
if (m_file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
    QTextStream in(&m_file);
    QString txt = in.readAll();
    QStringList lines = txt.split("\n");
   foreach (QString c, lines) {
    cookies.append(QNetworkCookie::parseCookies(c.toUtf8()));
   }
    m_file.close();
} 
setAllCookies(cookies);
```

Of Course, you'll also need a writing function, like so:

```
QTextStream out(&m_file);
        foreach (const QByteArray &cookie, m_rawCookies)
            out << cookie + "\n";
        m_file.close();
```

And your raw cookies like so:

```
QList<QNetworkCookie> cookies = allCookies();
m_rawCookies.clear();

foreach (const QNetworkCookie &cookie, cookies) {
  m_rawCookies.append(cookie.toRawForm());
}
```

If you download the webkit source, you can take a look at the testbrowser code for a more complete example.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could approach this is to not try to do it with QWebViews at all, but instead subclass QNetworkManager and hook its signals to snoop the QNetworkReplys that are sent back.

Otherwise in your second QWebView you could just set its content to the HTML you want to display and you might be able to enforce only grabbing data from the cache.

Comment: As it turns out, I accomlished this by subclassing QNetworkCookieJar and implementing my own filesystem store. Example code was found in the qwebkit source code for the test browser. The above is a good idea though. I am unsure if I should simply post an answer here...I don't want to always be answering my own questions...